# Facebook share/like callback

Tags: swift, facebook-ios-sdk

how I know if you did or not share? there is a method to see the callback

```
    let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "")
    content.contentTitle = ""
    content.contentDescription = ""
    content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "")

    let button12 : FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
    button12.shareContent = content
    button12.frame = CGRectMake(170,80, 70, 25)
    self.viewBotoes.addSubview(button12)
```

Comment: may i ask why do you need to know? what for exactly?

Comment: @luschn I wonder if the User could share or not

Comment: facebook made it extra-hard to find out for a very good reason, so what for exactly do you need to know?

Comment: @sddhhanover most have some method to allow this?

Comment: You will only know if the user actually shared or not if the user has authorized your app (i.e. logged in via Facebook to your app). Otherwise it will always be a "success" unless there was a server error.